# Android: Why do we need an IBinder for the Messenger to communicate with the Handler?

Tags: android, android-service, android-handler, android-binder

Talking in the context of the third snippet of code given [on this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html), there is a method of a [`Messenger` named `getBinder()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Messenger.html#send(android.os.Message)) which returns [the `IBinder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/IBinder.html) the `Messenger` is using to communicate with the [associated `Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

Now **why would we need an `IBinder` for the `Messenger` to communicate with the Handler, when a `Messenger` is a reference to the `Handler`, and both are created in the same `class`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Messenger` does "message-based communication across processes". Binder is "lightweight remote procedure call mechanism". Almost everything in android that sends data between processes uses Binders.